# Cloudflare API token permission to edit terraform cloudflare_list resource

Tags: cloudflare, terraform

Recently I had an [API Token](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/api-terraform/scoped-api-tokens/) that allowed me to access Terraform `cloudflare_access_rule` and `cloudflare_list` resources. That token expired, and to my surprise, it vanished from the UI, so I cannot see the configuration that was working before.

I managed to figure out that I need `Account Firewall Access Rules:Edit` for `cloudflare_access_rule`. But I still don't know what is needed for `cloudflare_list`. After trying many different permissions, I keep getting an error like this on `terraform plan`:

```
Error: error reading List with ID "vwn...": Authentication error (10000)
```

Could anyone tell me what permissions I need to add to the API Token to edit [cloudflare_list resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/list) with Terraform? And is there a better approach to find out what permissions are needed without trial and error?

One workaround was to use the `Read all resources` template with a new token, and that's fine for a `terraform plan`. But to actually make changes, I will need to know which permission to toggle from `Read` to `Edit`. I could of course, change all to Edit, or try the global API keys, but I prefer a more granular approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `cloudflare_list`, it depends on:

- [single](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/url-forwarding/single-redirects/create-api/#prerequisites): `Zone > Dynamic Redirect > Edit`
- [bulk](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/url-forwarding/bulk-redirects/create-api): `Account > Account Rulesets > Edit` and `Account > Account Filter Lists > Edit`

Comment: Thanks, tried both, still get the same error. Looking at the links provided, these don't seem to be the correct permissions, as I am not trying to do redirects.

Comment: Through a process of elimination I ended up with only: `All accounts - Account Filter Lists:Read, Account Firewall Access Rules:Edit`. Don't know why yours didn't work when I had tried, but seems like it should, so voting and accepting. Thanks.